# async, await not working as expected ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, async-await

Trying to figure out why this does not work and what I am missing.

From landing page I am making a call to function in a service

```
this.comms.updateAccessedState();
```

Inside service

```
 async updateAccessedState() {
   console.log("get this token 1");
   await this.getToken();
   console.log(`3 ${this.token}`);
 }
```

and

```
getToken() {
this._currentUser.getProfile().then((data) => {
  console.log("retrieve token 2");
  this.token = data.token;
});
```

When printing this out to the console

i get `get token => 1
       3 undefined
       retrieving token => 2`

why is the function not being 'awaited'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the method `getToken` `async`, and make it return a promise. Change it to this:

```
async getToken(): Promise<any> {
    return this._currentUser.getProfile().then((data) => {
      console.log("retrieve token 2");
      this.token = data.token;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work too.  I find it easier to not mix `async`/`await` with `then` if possible.

```
async getToken() {
    let data = await this._currentUser.getProfile();
    console.log("retrieve token 2");
    this.token = data.token;
});
```